# Courier-IMAP use another SMTP server

Tags: smtp, amazon-ses

I'm working on a server with Courier-IMAP installed as the Email server. However it seems all the mail sent out go to the Spam folder for Gmail and Hotmail accounts. I do have a SMTP server with Amazon SES that gets the mail into the Inboxes, I wonder if it's possible to config Courier-IMAP to use the Amazon SMTP server setting. I couldn't find anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courier is an IMAP server. It provides access to mailboxes.

You have an SMTP server / MTA on your machine that is delivering locally sent/generated mail to the IMAP mailboxes and external mailboxes ( Amazon, Google, AOL, etc.).  The popular SMTP / MTAs , one of which you probably have, are : exim postfix qmail sendmail .

You can configure apps directly to use Amazon's SMTP services.  You can also configure your local SMTP/MTA to relay to Amazon.

Whether you go for Amazon or not, all the large ISPs and Email providers are very vicious with their anti-spam policies.  Most require you to have something like Sender Policy Framework (SPF) or DomainKeys installed.  I think there's a new protocol too.  Yahoo and AOL require an active abuse@ account which they with ping with messages that have a unique link - they want to ensure that you're always checking that account.  If anything gets through into a junk mail folder, check the headers to see why it was marked as such - most of the large ESPs will add a header that states why something was marked as spam.

Answer (score 0):

According to author of software, the `/etc/courier/esmtpauthclient` should be configured like this, and it is working configuration on my server:

/etc/courier/esmtpauthclient:

```
:email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,587 AKISAMPLEPASSSUA AtHrTSAMPLEPASSWORDLiHJTt
```

and

/etc/courier/esmtproutes:

```
example.com: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com,587 /SECURITY=REQUIRED
```

And e-mail addresses and domains shall be verified with Amazon SES.